# Numpy array to csv

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I have a np array with 1000 rows, and 4608 columns each rows

I try to save a csv file with:

```
myfile = open('dataset.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(myfile,delimiter='\n')
wr.writerow(Prueba[0])
```

But if I open the csv file with LibreOffice this:

```
[153 147 147 ..., 142 147 146]  
[183 247 147 ..., 126 123 104]
...
```

No apears the 4608 columns!!

Some idea?

Thank you!

Regards, Andres.

Answer (score 8):

Try this.

```
numpy.savetxt("FILENAME.csv", a, delimiter=",")
```

Where filename is your filename and a is your array.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, but
This return the next error: TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e')

Comment: If all numbers are int, you can add the option `fmt='%d'`

Comment: Thanks Julien. All numbers are type <type 'numpy.uint8'>, I try its in then: TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%d')

Answer (score 1):

The type of the `array` and the `fmt` option must match. Try:

```
import numpy as np

np.savetxt('dataset.csv', array.astype(np.int), fmt='%d', delimiter=',')
```

where `array` is your numpy array.